# Looping an array inside mapping state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

This is my map code in react jsx

```
{this.state.nodes.map((node, index) => {
  return (
    <div
      key={index}
      className={"node " + node.className}
      id={node.id}
      ref={nodes => (this.refs.nodes[index] = nodes)}
      style={node.style}
      onClick={this.activeElem}
    >
      {node.text.text + "\n"}
      {showbutton ? (
        <div
          className="add-btn"
          onClick={event => this.editProcess(event, node, index)}
        >
          +
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p />
      )}

      {decisionbutton ? (
        <div
          className="add-btn"
          onClick={event => this.editProcess(event, node, index)}
        >
          +
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p />
      )}
      <div
        className="delete-btn"
        onClick={event => this.deleteNode(event, node)}
      >
        X
      </div>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

`{node.text}` is showing an Object Object in return but I cannot show the text inside

Node> text > text

How can i show this?

Comment: Could you format your code example so that is is a bit more readable?

Comment: You should be fine doing just `node.text.text`. Can you show more?

Comment: Please share the nodes array and sample of your desire output that you want on screen.

Comment: fard its undefined

Comment: Its have been updated

Comment: `JSON.stringify(node.text, null, 2)`  do this instead of `**{console.log(node.text)}**` and you will see that is inside `node.text`

Comment: I have tried this it is showing something like this

`[ { "textid": "4fd5e120-5f75-11e9-8845-df9a3a92daa9", "text": "asad" }, { "textid": "4fd5e120-5f75-11e9-8845-df9a3a92daa9", "text": "sadsf" }`

I want to see only the text how can i achieve this

Comment: It is showing Object Object because you're trying to display the text property assuming the object but actually it is an Array. You have to loop the array again to show the text.

Comment: Chirag How can i achieve this

Comment: By using the map function again. _.map((node.text || []), (child, index) => { return (<div>{child.text}</div>)})

Comment: Can you please try me in a code braces i cannot understand it Chirag

i have tried this 

`{map((node.text || []), (child, index) => { return (<div>{child.text}</div>) })}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippet for your reference. 
I have made the nodes array as best of my assumption. Please use your own state nodes array and follow the relevant changes in code.

```
    const nodes = [{
          id: 1,
          style: 'dummy data',
          className: 'dummy data',
          text: [
            { id: 1, text: 'text 1'},
            { id: 2, text: 'text 2'}
          ]
        }]

    {nodes.map((node, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className={"node " + node.className}
                  id={node.id}
                  ref={nodes => (this.refs.nodes[index] = nodes)}
                  style={node.style}
                  onClick={this.activeElem}
                >
                {(node.text|| []).map((child, key) => {
                  return (<div key={key}>
                    {child.text}
                    {showbutton && <div className="add-btn" onClick={event => this.editProcess(event, node, index)}>+</div>}
                    {decisionbutton && <div className="add-btn" onClick={event => this.editProcess(event, node, index)}>+</div>}
                    <div className="delete-btn" onClick={event => this.deleteNode(event, node)}>X</div>
                  </div>)
                })}
                </div>
              );
            })}
```

Comment: TypeError: `(node.text || []).map` is not a function  is not a function Chirag

   `{(node.text|| []).map((child,key)=>{
                 return (
                    <div key={key}>
                    {child.text}
                    </div>
                 );
               })}`